# Space Complexity of Invert a Binary Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, big-o

I was working on a problem Invert Binary Tree, in an iterative fashion.

CODE:

```
def swap(node):

    if node is None:
        return None

    temp = node.left
    node.left = node.right
    node.right = node.left


def levelOrder(root):
    if node is None:
        return None

    q = deque()
    node = root
    q.append(node)

    while q:
        currNode = q.popleft()

        if currNode.left:
            q.append(currNode.left)
        if currNode.right:
            q.append(currNode.right)

        swap(currNode)

    return root
```

I am not able to understand or calculate the best case and worst case Space complexity. Time complexity I am able to understand its O(N) because, we will have to visit every node, But I need some help in understanding space complexity(I did some googling and it says its O(N) for space also). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe, your queue will never have all N nodes in it at once.
However, in order to check the worst case space complexity, the maximum number of nodes that it can have, will be all the leaf nodes. In a perfectly balanced binary tree, the maximum number of leaf nodes will be (N/2). Hence the space complexity is O(N/2) which is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

The program requires O(n) extra space for storing  nodes in any level of the binary. The worst case happens when we have a full binary tree. In that case, the last level have n/2 number of nodes.
So the overall space complexity will O(n) for storing the nodes which will not go beyond n and time complexity will be O(n) as you are visiting all the nodes in the tree.